# MySQL query to search multiple attributes and value_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with mysql query. for a cuople days I cannot solve it.

URL params ?a=1&b=2&c=3

Structure:

attr_id
value_id

query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `product_id`
FROM `products_attr_val`
WHERE
    (`attr_id` = '".$searchqueryArray2[0]."' AND `value_id` = '".$searchqueryArray2[1]."')
    OR (`attr_id` = '".$searchqueryArray2[0]."' AND `value_id` = '".$searchqueryArray2[1]."')
```

but the problem is that if a=12&b=10

and if there is a product with atribute 10 or atribute 12 it shows. I need to show products with a=12 and b=10.

Whats wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use the `{}` button to properly format code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

```
SELECT
    `product_id`,
    COUNT (`primary_key_id`) AS `attr_count` /* primary key field here */
FROM `products_attr_val`
WHERE
   (`attr_id` = ? AND `value_id` = ?)
   OR (`attr_id` = ? AND `value_id` = ?)
   /* additional as necessary
   OR (`attr_id` = ? AND `value_id` = ?)
   */
GROUP BY `product_id`
HAVING `attr_count` = ? /* value here should be equal to number of attributes you are checking for */
```

Make sure you have a unique index across `product_id` and `attr_id` for this to work properly (you should already have this since it would not likely make sense for a product to have multiple records with the same `attr_id`).

You also need to make sure you are escaping your values for use in your SQL if you are not already. I am showing these variables here with `?` which, if you we using prepared statments, would be a way you might write this SQL.

Comment: yes, but products have attributes. its wheel shop. 

WIDTH
HEIGHT
MANUFACTURER.

So that attributes with width and height may have not only one tire.

Comment: still nothing. @Mike Brant

Comment: @saul  Yes even though there might be attributes such as width, height, etc. might apply to multiple products, each product should presumably only have one one value each for width, height, etc.  Thus why I mention the need to have a unique index across product id and attribute id, such that each combination of product id and attribute id are unique.  How is what I presented not working for you?

Comment: table `products_attr_val` 

`ID     product_id     attr_id      value_id
1         1             1              1 `
so this is wrong?

Comment: @saul That is just one row of the table. NOthing wrong with that.  There would be something wrong with adding a second row with values `2 1 1 2`.  You would have 2 different values for the same attribute on the same product, which would not seem to make sense. That is why you want a unique index as mentioned.  This would also mess up the query I suggested as you would have COUNT = 2 instead of 1 for this particular attribute.  SO are you having a problem with the query in my answer, or just not clear on how/why a unique index is needed?

Comment: Should I count all attributes in table or atributes in url params? 
?width=1&height=2 etc? 
@Mike Brant

Comment: @Saul As I mentioned in the comments in the query above, the value used in `HAVING` clause should equal the number of attributes you are querying against in your `WHERE` clause. SO if three parameters are passed, then there would be three conditions in `WHERE` clause joined by `OR` so you would use `HAVING attr_count = 3`

Comment: by the way, I'm using not MySQL, but mysql analog MariaDB. maby its because of that? @Mike Brant