# build sql query to select products based on multiple filters

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in my db: options (product characteristics), products and option_data, which links options with products. All tables have foreign keys and can be joined. [image: DB representation in excel]

How can I get the products based on their characteristics, eg. where `product_charX = 1` and where `product_charY = 2` etc.

Comment: Count the distinct option_date for each product. group by product having count(distinc toption_data) = #ofOptionsBeingConsidered.  Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388975/mysql-query-to-search-multiple-attributes-and-value-id

Comment: Welcome to the stack. We don't do pictures. Use text (see how others do it) or create a sqlfiddle. That way people don't spend 10 minutes at least recreating your world. And are more likely to help you and not downvote you.

Comment: yep this looks like a potential EAV

Comment: What do you mean by `product_charX` and `product_charY`? There are no columns by those names in the table.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for your comments, this is what I was looking for! Queries of such type perfectly work with my db. By the way, is EAV data model a bad database design choice?

Comment: @lyuba I find these approaches to be great; they follow normal form conventions and offer offer great flexibility.  You will find you may need to use dynamic SQL and Pivot queries to transform rows to columns at times: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for more info.  But this approach is widely accepted